# Inserting html form inside of script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Below is the script to delete records. And I tried to insert the form below with php variable to post that value within the same page. But I don't have an idea on how to insert it inside my script. And the script in my form is automatically submit.

I want to execute the form after the animation.

After this animation

```
$(this).parents(".record").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
                .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
```

Form

```
echo'
<form method="post" action="app_list2.php" id="dateForm" name="dateForm">
<div style="display:none;">
<input name="drop_1" type="hidden" value="'.$drop.'" style="background-color:blue;"><input name="tier_two" type="hidden" value="'.$tier_two.'">
<input type="submit" name="autosubmit"></div>
</form>';
echo'<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementsByName("autosubmit")[0].click(); // SUBMIT FORM
</script>';
```

}

Script

```
 <script>
$(function() {
$(".delbutton").click(function(){
var element = $(this);
var del_id = element.attr("id");
var info = 'id=' + del_id;
 if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this update? There is NO undo!"))
          {
 $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "delete.php",
   data: info,
   success: function(){
   }
 });
         $(this).parents(".record").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
        .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
 }
return false;
});
});
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last argument of `jQuery.animate()` will take a function that calls back when the animation is complete. In this case, you want it to show the form. You also want to set `style="display:none"` to your form's CSS to hide it until `$("#dateForm").show()` is called.

```
<?php

echo'
<form method="post" action="app_list2.php" id="dateForm" name="dateForm">
<div style="display:none;">
<input name="drop_1" type="hidden" value="'.$drop.'" style="background-color:blue;"><input name="tier_two" type="hidden" value="'.$tier_two.'">
<input type="submit" name="autosubmit"></div>
</form>';
}

?>

 <script>
$(function() {
$(".delbutton").click(function(){
var element = $(this);
var del_id = element.attr("id");
var info = 'id=' + del_id;
 if(confirm("Sure you want to delete this update? There is NO undo!"))
          {
 $.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "delete.php",
   data: info,
   success: function(){
   }
 });
    $(this).parents(".record").animate({ backgroundColor: "#fbc7c7" }, "fast")
        .animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow", function() {
            $("#dateForm").submit();
        });
 }
return false;
});
});
  </script>
```

Comment: I don't want to show the form. I want it to execute the form after the animation

Comment: you said "I want to insert this form below after the animation of hiding." -- which one do you want to do? execute it or show it?

Comment: sorry for that. What I mean is execute that form after that animation. Because in my page if I delete a record it shows the animation of hiding a table row. So that I want it to finish the animation before execute the form.

Answer (score 0):

Write the form's html inside a div, and set it's style="display:none;". This will make it invisible when the page loads. Then after your animation completes, you can call the [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) method on the form div to make it visible.
You'll need to define the callback function with your [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/). The following example taken from JQuery's [docs](http://api.jquery.com/) show how:

```
$( "#clickme" ).click(function() {
  $( "#book" ).animate({
    opacity: 0.25,
    left: "+=50",
    height: "toggle"
  }, 5000, function() {
    // This is the body of the callback function.
    // you need to make the form div visible from inside here
    // For example, $("#my-hidden-form-div").show()
  });
});
```

You can find more examples [here](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Comment: I'm not pointing for hiding script. I just want to post a value within the same page after that animation. So I want to insert the form after that animation.

Comment: The callback function is executed after the animation has finished. If you want to insert the form after the animation, you'll need to .append() it in the callback function.

Comment: so I can execute the form after the animation?

Comment: Yes. The code you write inside the callback will be executed after the animation has finished.